# Random in Spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Is there a built-in RANDOM method in Spring Data JPA like sort and pagination. Im using Hibernate, Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA. Btw im not using QueryDSL

Comment: Why and where do you want to use this random function in your data layer?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the pagination, but for sorting the column values...

In the interface, you can write something like this,

```
//Results are sorted in ascending order
public List<Person> findByLastNameOrderByLastNameAsc(String lastName);

//Results are sorted in descending order  
public List<Person> findByLastNameOrderByLastNameDesc(String lastName)
```

Click here for [Sorting](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-six-sorting/)

Please have a look [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/), for pagination. But this is not what you want to do I guess. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't answer the 'random' question at all..?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create a sub-class of http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html and use that to randomize it.

overload the "getOrderFor" method to randomly return "ASC" or "DESC" (without comparing the actual field value).